# How do you measure the length of time a specific visitor spends on a site?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I know it is against Google Analytics terms of service to store personal information about a user i.e. email address, log in name. But I have a requirement that need to track time spent on site/page for a user by email address.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Good question but a better fit for WebMasters SE.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are a bit more specific than that (if they weren't, google-analytics would not be usable on sites with user logins at all), but the question is why you need to track them by email address. As long as your user is logged in, all you have to do is set a session ID when they log in, and then track that session ID when it's being used for content requests. For PHP backends this is described in http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php but other server-side languages have similar functionality.

Comment: http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html see item 7 (Privacy), you are not alowed to store IP, email, user name or any other information that could identify a user.

Comment: No, the text is more specific: "You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track or collect personally identifiable information of Internet users", so you will not use the Google Analytics service to track your users. However, you are still perfectly free to write your own tracking, provided that uses your own user database. Not their service.

Comment: yea what I am looking for is an alternative service that maybe allows you to track users by time as Google Analytics doesn't, do you know of any off hand? DOn't mind if it is a subscription based service

Comment: hmm, none spring to mind. Most sites I know of maintain their own user database, with user logins, and short-lived anonymous session tracking based on IP, but because IPs can change, or can be organisational rather than individual, the latter aren't very reliable.